# A book about a girl who can hear thoughts and a boy who can read emotions

Tags: story-identification, books

The book's title might have contained the words: "feelings" "emotionless" "whispers" "Whispered" or something like that.

There are a boy and a girl. The girl I believe could hear or read other people's minds and she meets a boy that can feel other people's emotions. The only significant scene from the book that I can remember is a classroom setting and the boy was in his desk and he gave the girl a flower and she got up in front of him and threw the flower away, I believe.

Then he was able to tell she was sad, and he could read her because that was his ability or at least I am guessing that it was that.

Then there's another vague scene of them on the guy's porch, I believe and it was pouring rain and they were together.

The book's jacket was dark blue and on the front, the title was written in white wispy cursive letters as if they were being blown by the wind.

Comment: Can you tell us on which year more or less was it out? We don't know how old are you so saying it was when you were 12 or 13 doesn't say much.

Comment: What book did you think it was?

Answer (score 2):

The book is Whisper by Phoebe Kitanidis

If you or anyone need to look up books and only have a vague sense of plot/potential key words for title and such, maybe try Goodreads (I searched the word 'whisper' and scrolled for a bit)

(Also yes, I made an account JUST to answer this one question because I finally found that book today after years of trying to look for it on google XD)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think this might be the correct book, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It would help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.

Comment: An easy thing to do is to link to that Goodreads result. :) For me, linking the book and quoting the blurb are my first two steps. Plumbing the reviews for more details is generally the next step.